# Parseval's theorem for the Number Theoretic Transform

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform, discrete-time

What is Parseval's theorem for the [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform_(general)#Number-theoretic_transform) (aka Number Theoretic Transform)?

Namely, I have $\alpha$ a principal $n$th root of unity in a finite field $\mathbb{F}$ (say $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for $p$ prime) and for any $(\varphi_0,\dots,\varphi_{n-1})\in\mathbb{F}^n$, we define the transform $\hat{\varphi}\in\mathbb{F}^n$ via $$ \hat{\varphi}_k := \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\alpha^{jk}\varphi_j\,. $$

We have the orthogonality relation $$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\alpha^{jk} = \delta_{k,0} \qquad(k=0,\dots,n-1)$$

but what is the equivalent of [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) in this context? Since we don't have complex conjugation on $\mathbb{F}$ I am getting the weird relation $$ \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\varphi_j\psi_j = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\hat{\varphi}_j\hat{\psi}_{-j}\,. $$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your relation has nothing weird. For the DFT of length $n$, with $W_{jk} =\frac1{\sqrt{n}} e^{-2i\pi jk/n}$ Parseval is just saying that $u^\top (W v)=(u^\top W) v=(W^{-1}u)^\top v$ and $u^\top \overline{(Wv)}=u^\top W^{-1} \overline{v}=(Wu)^\top \overline{v}$. Also in a field we say primitive root of unity, principal root of unity mainly is for the difficulties arising when replacing $\Bbb{F}$ by a ring such as $\Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z}$ with $m$ composite. And you didn't check if $\sqrt{n}\in \Bbb{F}$ (for example $\sqrt6\not \in \Bbb{F}_7$)

Comment: When $\alpha=\zeta_n$ is in a finite extension of $\Bbb{F}_p$, if $p^k\equiv -1\bmod n$ for some $k$ then there is an automorphism of $\Bbb{F}_p(\zeta_n)$ sending $\zeta_n$ to $\zeta_n^{-1}$ which works as a substitute for the complex conjugaison.